# Ruby and Redis: set a timeout for subscribtions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, publish-subscribe

I'd like to wait for a message in a Redis channel for maximum 2 seconds, then I want the subscription to expire/timeout and stop blocking my code.

```
redis = Redis.new

redis.subscribe(channel) do |on|
  on.message do |channel, message|
    # ...
  end
end

# This line is never reached if no message is sent to channel :(
```

I'm using https://github.com/redis/redis-rb. I searched in the source but found no timeout option for subscriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a timeout block like this:

```
require 'timeout'

begin
  Timeout.timeout(2) do      
    redis.subscribe(channel) do |on|
      on.message do |channel, message|
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  # handle error: show user a message?
end
```

Comment: `Timeout.timeout` is not thread-safe https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/ the other answer is the way to go

Answer (score 6):

You can now [subscribe with a timeout](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#timeouts) in one step:

```
redis.subscribe_with_timeout(5, channel) do |on|
  on.message do |channel, message|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no timeout option in redis-rb pubsub implementation. However it could be quite easily built with tools you already have:

```
require 'redis'

channel = 'test'
timeout_channel = 'test_timeout'

timeout = 3

redis = Redis.new

redis.subscribe(channel, time_channel) do |on|
  timeout_at = Time.now + timeout

  on.message do |channel, message|
    redis.unsubscribe if channel == timeout_channel && Time.now >= timeout_at
  end

  # not the best way to do it, but we need something publishing to timeout_channel
  Thread.new {
    sleep timeout
    Redis.new.publish timeout_channel, 'ping'
  }
end

#This line is never reached if no message is sent to channel :(
puts "here we are!"
```

Main idea here is to have something publishing messages to a separate channel once in a while. Subscription client also subscribes for that special channel and checks current time to decide if it is timed out already.